# how to lmit values for a property of type string

Tags: .net, string

I have a class with a property that saves as string. However the values for the property can only be from a list of values, similar to an enum. However this list of values is loaded from a lookup table,so it may vary, therefore it can not be an enum.
I am talking to limit it in the type of the property and not validation nor in the GUI.
Any hints of how to achieve that?
Thanks in advance.

Edit: If I my list of values were known at design time, I would have an enum as the type for my property:

```
public enum MyValues{val1, val2, val3}

public class myClass
{
    ...
    public property MyValues myProp{get;set;}
}

...
myClass c1=new myClass();
c1.myProp=MyValues.val3;
```

However, as my values are loaded from a lookup table in the DB I cannot use enums.
EDIT 2: I would like to have something like:

```
public class MyValue:string
{
    public MyValue(string Val):base(val){} //this doesn't exist
}
public class MyValues:List<MyValue>
{
     public static MyValues GetValues()
     {
         //load values from DB;
        //plus All

     }
     public static MyValue ValueAll{get{return new MyValue("All")
}

public class myClass
{
    ...
    public property MyValue myProp{get;set;}
}

...
myClass c1=new myClass();
c1.myProp=MyValues.ValueAll;
//load combo with MyValues.GetValues();
c1.myProp = cboValues.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: What is the end result here? Why is validation out of the question?

Answer (score 2):

Property setters are full-fledged methods, and you can execute any code that you like within them. For example,

```
private string myProperty;
private HashSet<string> validValues;

public string MyProperty
{
    get { return myProperty; }
    set
    {
         if(!validValues.Contains(value)) throw new ArgumentException();

         myProperty = value;
    }
}
```

This is obviously a simple (and incomplete) example, but it should demonstrate what you need to do: in your setter, somehow validate that the supplied value (available in the `value` parameter, which is implicit) is valid. If it isn't, throw an exception (`ArgumentException` is the example used here and is fine, or feel free to throw a more specific or meaningful exception). If it is, set the value.

### Edit after Question Edit

The only real problem with your code is that you're trying to inherit from `string`, which is not allowed, though it's not really clear why you *need* to inherit from string. Make your property use `MyValue` as its type, bind `cboValues` to your list, then use `(MyValue)cboValues.SelectedItem` instead of `SelectedValue` to set your property.

Comment: It will not do. I don't want to validate but to limit the values.

Comment: Validation IS how you limit the values. You do realize an enum can contain any number an integer can contain, correct?

Comment: @Fer: You need to be specific about what you want, then.

Comment: xixonia: I know enums are integers but with enums the code is much more readable, and if a client dll uses my class the developer will know what kind of value has to go there. and validation IS NOT the same as limiting the values. A text box can take numbers and integers but if what you want the user to enter are just number you try to use a numeric box. It is just a better experience to avoid exceptions.

Comment: @Fer: Your issue is that "limiting the values" is vague and could legitimately be interpreted as validation, since validation does limit the values. You're on the right tracking your code; see my edit.

Comment: Adam: I wanted to inherit from string to just use MyValue as opposed of MyValue.Name. Having a property in the class MyValue breaks a few things in the presentation layer and adds code when the value needs to be read.

Comment: @Fer: What you're asking for isn't possible. The closest you could get would be to add an implicit conversion from `MyValue` to a `string`, but that won't work if your value is cast up above `MyValue` (to `object`, for example). If this doesn't work for you, then there is no way to do what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a value check in the property setter.

Answer (score 1):

As an example:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Foo
{
    HashSet<string> validBars = new HashSet<string>(){"Apple", "Orange", "Banana"};

    string bar = "Apple";
    public string Bar {
        get { return bar; }
        set {
            if(validBars.Contains(value)
                bar = value;
        }
    }
 }
```